# Convert field stored as Varchar to Timestamp, and eventually Date - Teradata

Tags: date, teradata, varchar

I have a timestamp field that has been stored as a Varchar in Teradata.

The original field contents looks like this '2018-01-30 21:19:20.000'.

I need to take it to a Date field in format 'YYYYMMDD', so I reckon I'd need to take it to actual Timestamp first before taking it to Date.

So I am able to convert that to actual Timestamp with this....

```
cast(CAST(time_stamp AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.S(6)') as Date FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') ..then I get a value in format 2018-11-26 00:00:00.000000
```

...but when converting to date, my date still comes out in format YYYY-MM-DD.

Is it possible to convert directly from VarChar to Date?

If so - how?

I need it to be in format YYYYMMDD and from what I've seen in Teradata Documentation, that isn't a valid format.

All assistance appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please be aware that ODBC itself applies format for DATE fields. So within the Database (and maybe in bteq or any export) your format will as desired - and then ODBC adds it's own format. You can work around by either putting it into an CHAR or amend the FormatPattern for date in your connection/DSN.

Answer (score 1):

FORMAT is only applied for Casts From/To string.

You can either

```
trim(cast(CAST(time_stamp AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.S(6)') as Date FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

or switch to

```
to_char(to_timestamp(time_stamp), 'YYYYMMDD')
```